# Heroku: Cannot access logs

Tags: logging, heroku, permissions

While trying to tail the logs for an api hosted on Heroku:

```
heroku logs --tail --app production
```

I get the following message:

```
!    You do not have access to the app production.
```

I've tailed these logs a million times before. I can still deploy to the production server, as well as I've logged out and back in again. Nothing seems to be working. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you maybe mean "--remote production"? Are you really the owner of the app "production" on heroku?

Comment: Can you please close this question?